# Library like ENet, but for TCP?

Tags: c++, networking

I'm not looking to use boost::asio, it is overly complex for my needs.

I'm building a game that is cross platform, for desktop, iPhone and Android.

I found a library called ENet which is pretty much what I need, but it uses UDP which does not seem to support encryption and a few other things.  Given that the game is an event driven card game, TCP seems like the right fit.

However, all I have found is WINSOCK / berkley sockets and bost::asio.

Here is a sample client server application with ENet:

```
#include <enet/enet.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

class Host
{
    ENetAddress address;
    ENetHost * server;
    ENetHost* client;
    ENetEvent event;
public:
    Host()
        :server(NULL)
    {
        enet_initialize();
        setupServer();
    }

    void setupServer()
    {
        if(server)
        {
            enet_host_destroy(server);
            server = NULL;
        }

        address.host = ENET_HOST_ANY;
        /* Bind the server to port 1234. */
        address.port = 1721;

        server = enet_host_create (& address /* the address to bind the server host to */, 
            32      /* allow up to 32 clients and/or outgoing connections */,
            2      /* allow up to 2 channels to be used, 0 and 1 */,
            0      /* assume any amount of incoming bandwidth */,
            0      /* assume any amount of outgoing bandwidth */);

    }

     void daLoop()
     {
         while(true)
         {
             /* Wait up to 1000 milliseconds for an event. */
             while (enet_host_service (server, & event, 5000) > 0)
             {
                 ENetPacket * packet;

                 switch (event.type)
                 {
                 case ENET_EVENT_TYPE_CONNECT:
                     printf ("A new client connected from %x:%u.\n", 
                         event.peer -> address.host,
                         event.peer -> address.port);

                     /* Store any relevant client information here. */
                     event.peer -> data = "Client information";

                     /* Create a reliable packet of size 7 containing "packet\0" */
                     packet = enet_packet_create ("packet", 
                         strlen ("packet") + 1, 
                         ENET_PACKET_FLAG_RELIABLE);

                     /* Extend the packet so and append the string "foo", so it now */
                     /* contains "packetfoo\0"                                      */
                     enet_packet_resize (packet, strlen ("packetfoo") + 1);
                     strcpy ((char*)& packet -> data [strlen ("packet")], "foo");

                     /* Send the packet to the peer over channel id 0. */
                     /* One could also broadcast the packet by         */
                     /* enet_host_broadcast (host, 0, packet);         */
                     enet_peer_send (event.peer, 0, packet);
                     /* One could just use enet_host_service() instead. */
                     enet_host_flush (server);

                     break;

                 case ENET_EVENT_TYPE_RECEIVE:
                     printf ("A packet of length %u containing %s was received from %s on channel %u.\n",
                         event.packet -> dataLength,
                         event.packet -> data,
                         event.peer -> data,
                         event.channelID);

                     /* Clean up the packet now that we're done using it. */
                     enet_packet_destroy (event.packet);

                     break;

                 case ENET_EVENT_TYPE_DISCONNECT:
                     printf ("%s disconected.\n", event.peer -> data);

                     /* Reset the peer's client information. */

                     event.peer -> data = NULL;
                 }
             }
         }

     }

        ~Host()
    {
        if(server)
        {
            enet_host_destroy(server);
            server = NULL;
        }

        atexit (enet_deinitialize);
    }
};

class Client
{
    ENetAddress address;
    ENetEvent event;
    ENetPeer *peer;
    ENetHost* client;
public:
    Client()
        :peer(NULL)
    {
        enet_initialize();
        setupPeer();
    }

    void setupPeer()
    {

        client = enet_host_create (NULL /* create a client host */,
            1 /* only allow 1 outgoing connection */,
            2 /* allow up 2 channels to be used, 0 and 1 */,
            57600 / 8 /* 56K modem with 56 Kbps downstream bandwidth */,
            14400 / 8 /* 56K modem with 14 Kbps upstream bandwidth */);

        if (client == NULL)
        {
            fprintf (stderr, 
                "An error occurred while trying to create an ENet client host.\n");
            exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        /* Connect to some.server.net:1234. */
        enet_address_set_host (& address, "192.168.2.13");
        address.port = 1721;

        /* Initiate the connection, allocating the two channels 0 and 1. */
        peer = enet_host_connect (client, & address, 2, 0);    

        if (peer == NULL)
        {
            fprintf (stderr, 
                "No available peers for initiating an ENet connection.\n");
            exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        /* Wait up to 5 seconds for the connection attempt to succeed. */
        if (enet_host_service (client, & event, 20000) > 0 &&
            event.type == ENET_EVENT_TYPE_CONNECT)
        {
            std::cout << "Connection to some.server.net:1234 succeeded." << std::endl;
        }
        else
        {
            /* Either the 5 seconds are up or a disconnect event was */
            /* received. Reset the peer in the event the 5 seconds   */
            /* had run out without any significant event.            */
            enet_peer_reset (peer);

            puts ("Connection to some.server.net:1234 failed.");
        }
    }


    void daLoop()
    {
        ENetPacket* packet;

        /* Create a reliable packet of size 7 containing "packet\0" */
        packet = enet_packet_create ("backet", 
            strlen ("backet") + 1, 
            ENET_PACKET_FLAG_RELIABLE);

        /* Extend the packet so and append the string "foo", so it now */
        /* contains "packetfoo\0"                                      */
        enet_packet_resize (packet, strlen ("backetfoo") + 1);
        strcpy ((char*)& packet -> data [strlen ("backet")], "foo");

        /* Send the packet to the peer over channel id 0. */
        /* One could also broadcast the packet by         */
        /* enet_host_broadcast (host, 0, packet);         */
        enet_peer_send (event.peer, 0, packet);
        /* One could just use enet_host_service() instead. */
        enet_host_flush (client);

        while(true)
        {
            /* Wait up to 1000 milliseconds for an event. */
            while (enet_host_service (client, & event, 1000) > 0)
            {
                ENetPacket * packet;

                switch (event.type)
                {
                case ENET_EVENT_TYPE_RECEIVE:
                    printf ("A packet of length %u containing %s was received from %s on channel %u.\n",
                        event.packet -> dataLength,
                        event.packet -> data,
                        event.peer -> data,
                        event.channelID);

                    /* Clean up the packet now that we're done using it. */
                    enet_packet_destroy (event.packet);

                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    ~Client()
    {
        atexit (enet_deinitialize);
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::string a;
    std::cin >> a;
    if(a == "host")
    {
        Host host;
        host.daLoop();
    }
    else
    {
        Client c;
        c.daLoop();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I looked at some socket tutorials and they seemed a bit too low level.

I just need something that abstracts away the platform (eg, no WINSOCKS) and that has basic ability to keep track of connected clients and send them messages.

Thanks

Comment: Have you considered HTTP/HTTPS? It uses TCP, has encryption, is easy to debug, has countless available tools and client/server libraries, works with proxies and most complex network setups…

Comment: TCP doesn't support encryption either. UDP and TCP are low level (transport layer) protocols, encryption is on a higher level (application level). You could just encrypt packets with any available encryption library, and it doesn't matter if packets are UDP or TCP.

Comment: @MartinSall: Rolling your own packet encryption has all sorts of pitfalls, though. (For example, do you know what a [replay attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Replay_attack) is and how to prevent them?) Using an existing protocol like [SSL/TLS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security) (or [DTLS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Datagram_Transport_Layer_Security)) is usually safer and easier, since others will have already done the work for you.

Comment: Standard secure communication works over UDP too, via http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Datagram_Transport_Layer_Security

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you control the coding of both server and client, [RakNet](http://www.jenkinssoftware.com/) could be something you might want to look into. It is not strictly TCP only. So if you decide that later you want to switch back to UDP, for whatever reason, it would be a painless transition.

Comment: I have seen RakNet but was turned off by its many licensing fees.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the [Unicomm](http://libunicomm.org) library will be suitable for you. It wraps Boost.Asio and provides high-level abstraction for the communication setup.

Answer (score -1):

Well Enet is even use by league of legends. And it work pretty fine. Keep it and use blowfish as encryption.